# PhpStorm, multiple Vagrant boxes, and xdebug

Tags: vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

I've got two vagrant machines, "front-end" and "back-end". "front-end" communicates with "back-end" via curl.

If I hit "back-end" from Postman, my breakpoints work. If I hit "front-end" from a web browser, my breakpoints in "front-end" work but the ones in "back-end" do not work.

In Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Debug, I've set Max. simultaneous connections to 20.

What am I missing?

Comment: How did you configure your xdebug? Does it starts debugging automatically (on every page/script execution) .. or does it require cookie/parameter in order to do that?

Comment: @LazyOne I pretty much know nothing about xdebug, but does giving you my config help? I have a different idekey and remote_host for each VM. The IP address is the VM's IP address.

zend_extension = "/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so"

xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.idekey = “723453467”
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.scream = 1
xdebug.cli_color = 1
xdebug.show_local_vars = 1
xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.50.42
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1

Comment: Well ... you have `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1` -- this option will override `xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.50.42`. if request is passed from front-end to back-end .. the xdebug will be attempting to connect to front-end instead of your IDE. That's what I can say from these settings.

Comment: @LazyOne That worked. Thanks! I can't accept the comment as the solution, but if you post it as an answer, I'll mark that as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1` -- this option will override any values that you have set for `xdebug.remote_host`.

When you send requests directly to back-end, xdebug connects to the IDE because requestor IP matches IP where IDE is running. But if request is sent from front-end to back-end then xdebug will be attempting to connect back to front-end (actual requestor) instead of your IDE.

You need to set `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0` and provide correct IP/host name for `xdebug.remote_host`.